# Docker build of node project fails on cloud-profiler pprof install

Tags: node.js, docker, node-gyp

I'm trying to build a docker image using https://github.com/coralproject/talk  on an M2 MacBookPro (MacOS 12.4, Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f) and I need help with the following error, which seems to revolve around `npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-profiler/pprof-nodejs/release/v3.2.0/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl.tar.gz #15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for pprof@3.2.0 and node@14.21.2 (node-v83 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)`:

```
tech@M-MacBook-Pro ~/c/talk (main)> docker build  .                                (base)
[+] Building 58.3s (15/15) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.41kB                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 456B                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14-alpine                             1.4s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                   0.0s
 => [ 1/10] FROM docker.io/library/node:14-alpine@sha256:2c6a909495ef3761328c10945cbe84c06d0  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                             0.6s
 => => transferring context: 12.09MB                                                          0.6s
 => CACHED [ 2/10] RUN apk --no-cache add git python3                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/10] RUN npm install -g npm@8.0.0                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/10] RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/10] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/10] COPY . /usr/src/app                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/10] RUN mkdir -p dist/core/common/__generated__ &&   echo "{"revision": "${RE  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/10] RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/10] RUN git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf ssh://git@git  0.0s
 => ERROR [10/10] RUN npm ci &&   npm run build &&   npm prune --production                  56.2s
------
 > [10/10] RUN npm ci &&   npm run build &&   npm prune --production:
#15 11.07 npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
#15 11.14 npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
#15 11.71 npm WARN deprecated url-regex-safe@2.1.0: Please upgrade to url-regex-safe@v3.0.0+ AND install re2 as an additional dependency in your project via `npm install re2` or `yarn add re2`.
#15 12.28 npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
#15 12.89 npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.19: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
#15 12.90 npm WARN deprecated svgo@0.7.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
#15 12.97 npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
#15 12.99 npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
#15 12.99 npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
#15 13.38 npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
#15 13.50 npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
#15 13.69 npm WARN deprecated signal-numbers@0.2.2: This package is no longer maintained.
#15 14.22 npm WARN deprecated react-axe@3.5.4: deprecated
#15 15.67 npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
#15 16.16 npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
#15 18.83 npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
#15 18.94 npm WARN deprecated graphql-extensions@0.16.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
#15 19.10 npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
#15 19.41 npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
#15 19.42 npm WARN deprecated fluent-intl-polyfill@0.1.0: Please use intl-pluralrules instead
#15 22.68 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-types@0.10.0: The `apollo-server-types` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 22.69 npm WARN deprecated apollo-tracing@0.16.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
#15 22.69 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-plugin-base@0.10.4: The `apollo-server-plugin-base` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 22.70 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-errors@2.5.0: The `apollo-server-errors` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 22.71 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-plugin-response-cache@0.5.8: The `apollo-server-plugin-response-cache` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server-plugin-response-cache` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 22.76 npm WARN deprecated apollo-datasource@0.10.0: The `apollo-datasource` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 22.76 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-express@2.26.1: The `apollo-server-express` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 22.78 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-caching@0.7.0: This package is part of the legacy caching implementation used by Apollo Server v2 and v3, and is no longer maintained. We recommend you switch to the newer Keyv-based implementation (which is compatible with all versions of Apollo Server). See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v3/performance/cache-backends#legacy-caching-implementation for more details.
#15 22.79 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-env@3.2.0: The `apollo-server-env` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/utils.fetcher` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 22.97 npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.15.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
#15 23.05 npm WARN deprecated apollo-reporting-protobuf@0.8.0: The `apollo-reporting-protobuf` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/usage-reporting-protobuf` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 23.20 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-core@2.26.1: The `apollo-server-core` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 24.45 npm WARN deprecated @types/xregexp@4.4.0: This is a stub types definition. xregexp provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
#15 25.90 npm WARN deprecated @types/react-axe@3.5.0: This is a stub types definition. react-axe provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
#15 27.85 npm WARN deprecated @types/eventemitter2@4.1.0: This is a stub types definition for eventemitter2 (https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2). eventemitter2 provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/eventemitter2 installed!
#15 28.64 npm WARN deprecated @types/classnames@2.3.1: This is a stub types definition. classnames provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
#15 28.77 npm WARN deprecated @types/bson@4.2.0: This is a stub types definition. bson provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
#15 30.12 npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
#15 38.99 npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
#15 40.36 npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
#15 40.51 npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.4.1: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
#15 41.43 npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
#15 43.62 npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
#15 44.29 npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
#15 44.65 npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
#15 44.83 npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
#15 44.86 npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
#15 44.91 npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
#15 45.85 npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
#15 46.31 npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
#15 46.51 npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
#15 46.81 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-plugin-base@0.14.0: The `apollo-server-plugin-base` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 46.81 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-types@0.6.3: The `apollo-server-types` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 46.86 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-plugin-base@0.14.0: The `apollo-server-plugin-base` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 46.86 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-caching@0.5.3: This package is part of the legacy caching implementation used by Apollo Server v2 and v3, and is no longer maintained. We recommend you switch to the newer Keyv-based implementation (which is compatible with all versions of Apollo Server). See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v3/performance/cache-backends#legacy-caching-implementation for more details.
#15 46.86 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-caching@0.5.3: This package is part of the legacy caching implementation used by Apollo Server v2 and v3, and is no longer maintained. We recommend you switch to the newer Keyv-based implementation (which is compatible with all versions of Apollo Server). See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v3/performance/cache-backends#legacy-caching-implementation for more details.
#15 46.87 npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-plugin-base@0.14.0: The `apollo-server-plugin-base` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 47.29 npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.11.6: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
#15 47.50 npm WARN deprecated apollo-reporting-protobuf@0.6.2: The `apollo-reporting-protobuf` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/usage-reporting-protobuf` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
#15 47.54 npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
#15 56.00 npm notice
#15 56.00 npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.0.0 -> 9.3.0
#15 56.00 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.3.0>
#15 56.00 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.3.0` to update!
#15 56.00 npm notice
#15 56.00 npm ERR! code 1
#15 56.00 npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof
#15 56.00 npm ERR! command failed
#15 56.00 npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
#15 56.00 npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl/pprof.node --module_name=pprof --module_path=/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@14.21.2 | linux | arm64
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl/pprof.node" (not found)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-profiler/pprof-nodejs/release/v3.2.0/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl.tar.gz
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-profiler/pprof-nodejs/release/v3.2.0/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl.tar.gz
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for pprof@3.2.0 and node@14.21.2 (node-v83 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-profiler/pprof-nodejs/release/v3.2.0/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl.tar.gz
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.21.2 | linux | arm64
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info ok
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.21.2 | linux | arm64
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.9 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.21.2/node-v14.21.2-headers.tar.gz
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.21.2/node-v14.21.2-headers.tar.gz
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.21.2/SHASUMS256.txt
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.21.2/SHASUMS256.txt
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/config.gypi',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/node/.cache/node-gyp/14.21.2/include/node/common.gypi',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/node/.cache/node-gyp/14.21.2',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/node/.cache/node-gyp/14.21.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info ok
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.21.2 | linux | arm64
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:10:17)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:18
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:54:21)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:71:22
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at subStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:33)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:22
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.49-linuxkit
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl/pprof.node" "--module_name=pprof" "--module_path=/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.21.2
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
#15 56.00 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl/pprof.node --module_name=pprof --module_path=/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v83-linux-arm64-musl --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.49-linuxkit
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.21.2
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.10
#15 56.00 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
#15 56.04
#15 56.04 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#15 56.04 npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2023-01-15T20_16_23_713Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm ci &&   npm run build &&   npm prune --production]: exit code: 1
tech@M-MacBook-Pro ~/c/talk (main) [1]>
```

All thoughts gladly received!

Answer (score 0):

Are there any pre-settings to be made before running docker compose up command? Do I need to create environment variables or they have been pre- setted? Or maybe any container needs to be up and running already? I tried to run it on my machine and I got the following:

[docker program in my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN3eS.png)

Comment: Do you have Docker running on your machine? That's a precondition.

Comment: Yes, did you look the print, it didn't run on my machine either, but it was a connection issue